# Check if the score is a multiple of 10 - Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, for-loop, colors

I created a game few times ago and I want to update the code. There is a score which increases one by one.

Every decade, the background change to another color. I created 40 colors like that (I used an extension to use Hex colors) :

```
let color1 = SKColor(netHex: 0xFF6C5C)
let color2 = SKColor(netHex: 0x1297E0)
[...]
let color40 = SKColor(netHex: 0x9E6C4B)
```

In the update function, I created an `if statement` for each decade (up to 400) :

```
if score == 10 {

        self.backgroundColor = color1

}

if score == 20 {

        self.backgroundColor = color2

}

[...]

if score == 400 {

        self.backgroundColor = color40

}
```

I want to use a `for loop` because there is too many lines of code.

First, I moved all the colors in an array :

```
let colorsArray = [

    SKColor(netHex: 0xFF6C5C), // COLOR 1
    SKColor(netHex: 0x1297E0), // COLOR 2
    [...]
    SKColor(netHex: 0xFF6C5C), // COLOR 40

]
```

I placed this `for loop` in the update function... :

```
for let index = 10; index < 400; index + 10 {

        if score == index {

            let colorIndex = index / 10 - 1
            self.backgroundColor = colorsArray[colorIndex]

        }

}
```

...but the application crashed.

I think the update function is not the right place for this `for loop` to be executed. Anyone can help me ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the colors into an array was the right approach.

There is no need to iterate through a loop to determine the colorIndex, just use an integer division:

```
let colorIndex = score / 10
self.backgroundColor = colorsArray[colorIndex]
```

This gives 0 for a score of 0-9, 1 for a score of 10-19, ... and 39 for a score of 390-399...

Comment: Thanks a lot, two simple line instead of 700, it changes everything :)

Answer (score 0):

What was the actual error? That would help me figure out where things are going wrong. You could Try commenting out the individual lines in the for loop to try to isolate the problem.

Also instead of doing the loop you can just use modulo (%) to see if the number is divisible by 10 rather than looping...

Comment: @zisoft gave me the solution, thank you for your answer ! :)